# Virtual file system in php?

Tags: php, file-upload, download, virtualfilesystem

We have a system where, a large part of it is the ability to upload and download files if you are logged in and have the correct permissions.

What we are looking at doing to help with the organization from the users point of view is having a virtual file system type layout.

Even if (or even preferably) all the users files are actually just stored in one directory, and the virtual file system is just a screen put up from the database.

What we are wondering before we invest in creating this is if this already exists somewhere, open source (but able to be used in commercial software), free, or paid (first two preferably!).

Comment: It sounds to me that you are building an online FTP server ... http://www.ajaxline.com/best-web-based-ftp-managers

Comment: see if https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

A simple file system on top of PHP can be done by WebDAV that is built on top of PHP:

http://sabre.io/

This would be a good example, but there are others as well. WebDAV is essentially a web based file system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).

This could not only provide a file system, but also would let you edit files directly with Word/Excel (2007+) in it. Showing then a treeview of folders and files would be quite trivial, using few database tables and some jquery components, such as jsTree and jqGrid.

Although if you are searching for a full document management system: http://www.opendocman.com/ or http://code.google.com/p/simpledoc/ this would be more then enough.

It really depends on how many features you are going to incorporate into this system. Will there be an OCR, would you like to store the files in the cloud service, how many user input there will be (is simple upload enough, or camera, scanners and other devices are needed to be used as well)?

As for the commercial products, you could check out Microsoft SharePoint (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) or IBM Lotus Notes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lotus_Notes)